# Zend Soap Client tag names

Tags: zend-framework, soap

**I'm trying to connect a .net WSDL service with Zend Soap Client. I use the code below;**

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("http://ws.test.com/test/services/service.asmx", array(

        'uri'   =>  'http://tempuri.org',
        'soap_version'  =>  SOAP_1_1,
        'wsdl'  => 'http://ws.test.com/test/services/service.asmx?wsdl'
));

$client->DoInventoryItemImport(array(
    'DepositorID_'  =>  '123',
    'UserName_'     =>  'ABC',
    'Password_'     =>  '123123',
    'SecurityKey_'  =>  '',
    'ContinueOnError_'  => true,
    'Items_'    => array(
        'InventoryItem' =>  array(
            'Code'              =>  'testcode',
            'Description'       =>  'test description',
            'Abccode'           =>  'test',
            'Weight'            =>  10.10,
            'ItemMainCategory'  =>  'testCategory',
            'Depositor'         =>  'ABC',
            'DepositorCode'     =>  '123'
        )
    )

));
```

**This code sends a soap envelope exactly like this one;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:DoInventoryItemImport>
            <ns1:Items_>
                <ns1:InventoryItem>
                    <ns1:Code>testcode</ns1:Code>
                    <ns1:Description>test description</ns1:Description>
                    <ns1:Abccode>test</ns1:Abccode>
                    <ns1:AllocatesAgainstQCPolicy xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:SafetyStockCU xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:TemplateItem xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:MinimumOrderQTY xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:IsLoadBatch xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:Weight>10.1</ns1:Weight>
                    <ns1:Volume xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:Diameter xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:IsTemporaryItem xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:IsKitItem xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:ItemMainCategory>testCategory</ns1:ItemMainCategory>
                    <ns1:IsFragile xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:IsPackingItem xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns1:Depositor>ABC</ns1:Depositor>
                    <ns1:DepositorCode>123</ns1:DepositorCode>
                </ns1:InventoryItem>
            </ns1:Items_>
            <ns1:UserName_>ABC</ns1:UserName_>
            <ns1:Password_>123123</ns1:Password_>
            <ns1:SecurityKey_></ns1:SecurityKey_>
            <ns1:ContinueOnError_>true</ns1:ContinueOnError_>
        </ns1:DoInventoryItemImport>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**But as I understand from their service definition, they want a soap envelope like this one;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <DoInventoryItemImport xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Items_>
                <InventoryItem>
                    <Code>testcode</Code>
                    <Description>test description</Description>
                    <Abccode>test</Abccode>
                    <AllocatesAgainstQCPolicy>true</AllocatesAgainstQCPolicy>
                    <SafetyStockCU>1</SafetyStockCU>
                    <TemplateItem>true</TemplateItem>
                    <MinimumOrderQTY>1</MinimumOrderQTY>
                    <IsLoadBatch>true</IsLoadBatch>
                    <Weight>10.1</Weight>
                    <Volume>1</Volume>
                    <Diameter>1</Diameter>
                    <IsTemporaryItem>true</IsTemporaryItem>
                    <IsKitItem>true</IsKitItem>
                    <ItemMainCategory>testCategory</ItemMainCategory>
                    <IsFragile>true</IsFragile>
                    <IsPackingItem>true</IsPackingItem>
                    <Depositor>ABC</Depositor>
                    <DepositorCode>123</DepositorCode>
                </InventoryItem>
            </Items_>
            <UserName_>ABC</UserName_>
            <Password_>123123</Password_>
            <SecurityKey_></SecurityKey_>
            <ContinueOnError_>true</ContinueOnError_>
        </DoInventoryItemImport>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Actually these envelopes contains same data and their structure matches. But I don't know how to change tag names like SOAP-ENV to soap and remove prefixes like "ns1:".

I think I am misconfiguring my Zend Soap Client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by overloading Zend Soap Client. I used str_ireplace function to replace 'ns1:' with '' on request variable. Then I used my custom client to connect. Hope this helps to somebody.

```
class My_Client extends Zend_Soap_Client_DotNet{

    public function _doRequest(Zend_Soap_Client_Common $client, $request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null)
    {
        if ($one_way == null) {
            return call_user_func(array($client,'SoapClient::__doRequest'), str_ireplace('ns1:', '', $request), $location, $action, $version);
        } else {
            return call_user_func(array($client,'SoapClient::__doRequest'), str_ireplace('ns1:', '', $request), $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        }
    }

}
```